# Expected identifier or ( error

Tags: ios, objective-c

i get this error "Expected identifier or (" in my code, and i getting it at the  "{" before 
-(void)viewDidAppear in the m-file, i thinking about if i have missed something like a bracket or something like that..

**h-file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface WalkingTableViewController: UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *MKMapView;
@end
```

**m-file**

```
#import "WalkingTableViewController.h"

@interface UITableViewController ()

@end

@implementation WalkingTableViewController


- (IBAction)StopButton:(id)sender 
{
}

- (IBAction)StartButton:(id)sender 
{
}

@end

{

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidLoad]
    self.MKMapView.showsUserLocation=YES;
    self.MKMapView.delegate = self;
    [self.MKMapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];
    [super viewDidAppear:animated]
    CLLocationManager* tempLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    MKCoordinateRegion tRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([tempLocationManager.location           coordinate], 1000,1000);
    [self.MKMapView setRegion:tRegion animated:animated];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah this is spurious and should be removed:

```
    @end

{
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that line but that just seems to obvious, and so does the miss `;`